# Eclipse: LogCat window keeps closing

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Using Eclipse version 3.7.2

The LogCat window, in the Java perspective, keeps disappearing. This might sound like a ridiculous question, but how do I keep it in the view permanently? I searched other questions, and most of them seem to be about getting rid of LogCat - the opposite of my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Go in "Windows" in the top Menu bar of the Eclipse. and select "Reset Perspective". It will solve your problem..

Comment: Answered my own question, but the interface won't let me post it for 8 hours.... Tried clicking the "Show View As A Fast View" menu button in the lower left, and that (properly or improperly) fixed the issue. LogCat stays visible now.

Comment: Thanks YuDroid for that suggestion as well

Comment: Please answer your question yourself and accept the answer to close that topic

Comment: @andrew.bober can you include a screenshot? I cannot see that option in the lower left.